# Split a list using another list whose items are the split lengths

Tags: python

I want to split a list using another list which contains the lengths of each split.

E.g:

```py
>>> print list(split_by_lengths(list('abcdefg'), [2,1]))
... [['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']]
>>> print list(split_by_lengths(list('abcdefg'), [2,2]))
... [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]    
>>> print list(split_by_lengths(list('abcdefg'), [2,2,6]))
... [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
>>> print list(split_by_lengths(list('abcdefg'), [1,10]))
... [['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']]
>>> print list(split_by_lengths(list('abcdefg'), [2,2,6,5]))
... [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
```

As you can notice, if the lengths list does not cover all the list I append the remaining elements as an additional sublist. Also, I want to avoid empty lists at the end in the cases that the lengths list produces more elements that are in the list to split.

I already have a function that works as I want:

```py
def take(n, iterable):
    "Return first n items of the iterable as a list"
    return list(islice(iterable, n))

def split_by_lengths(list_, lens):
    li = iter(list_)
    for l in lens:
        elems = take(l,li)
        if not elems:
            break
        yield elems
    else:
        remaining = list(li)
        if remaining:
           yield remaining
```

But I wonder if there is a more pythonic way to write a function such that one.

*Note:* I grabbed `take(n, iterable)` from [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

*Note:* This question is a repost from a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22857572/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22857694/846892) that I gave on stackoverflow:

```
from itertools import islice

def split_by_lengths(seq, num):
    it = iter(seq)
    for n in num:
        out = list(islice(it, n))
        if out:
            yield out
        else:
            return   #StopIteration 
    remain = list(it)
    if remain:
        yield remain
```

Here I am not using a for-else loop because we can end the generator by using a simple `return` statement. And IMO there's no need to define an extra `take` function just to slice an iterator.

**Second answer:**

This one is slightly different from the first one because this won't **short-circuit** as soon as one of the length exhausts the iterator. But it is more compact compared to my first answer.

```
def split_by_lengths(seq, num):
    it = iter(seq)
    out =  [x for x in (list(islice(it, n)) for n in num) if x]
    remain = list(it)
    return out if not remain else out + [remain]
```

Comment: Agreed that `take(n, iterable)` is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by just slicing the sequence — there's really no advantage to having a helper function like`take()`. I also added a keyword argument to make the returning of anything remaining optional.

```
def split_by_lengths(sequence, lengths, remainder=True):
    last, SequenceLength = 0, len(sequence)
    for length in lengths:
        if last >= SequenceLength: return  # avoid empty lists
        adjacent = last + length
        yield sequence[last:adjacent]
        last = adjacent
    if last < SequenceLength and remainder:
        yield sequence[last:]

print list(split_by_lengths(list('abcdefg'), [2, 1]))
# [['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']]
print list(split_by_lengths(list('abcdefg'), [2, 2]))
# [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
print list(split_by_lengths(list('abcdefg'), [2, 2, 6]))
# [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
print list(split_by_lengths(list('abcdefg'), [1, 10]))
# [['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']]
print list(split_by_lengths(list('abcdefg'), [2, 2, 6, 5]))
# [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
```